# How can I play a crazy character?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I would like to try playing a "Lunatic" and/or "Possessed" character, because I heard they have some really entertaining events.

Is there a reliable way to drive my current or next character crazy?

When there isn't, is there a moderately powerful and young historical nutjob I could play?

<strike>Because I am a cheapskate</strike> to keep this question useful for a wide audience I would prefer an answer which doesn't require any DLC (so ruler designer is out of the question).

Comment: The latter part of the question (i.e. if there is someone with this trait by default) was interesting, pity it wasn't answered.

Comment: @Lohoris You might consider [placing a bounty on the question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) to encourage someone to answer this too. I, for one, am not interested anymore because a while after posting this questions I noticed that in one of my savegames one of my most powerful dukes is a Lunatic, so I continued playing as him.

Comment: Considering the current answers ignore it, and it's technically another question, we could just post it as another question, instead.

Answer (score 9):

The Lunatic and Possessed traits are given by events. In the base game, these events can happen randomly. There are other ways to gain the traits or to make these events more likely but, as far as I can recall, all are in DLCs.

The easiest way to add these traits, without ruler designer, is to cheat and use the console. To do this, you need to be in a non-ironman game. Press the <kbd>`</kbd> key (it's the one to the left of the <kbd>1</kbd> key) to open the console.

The code to trigger events is

```
event (eventID)
```

The specific events you want are:

Lunatic:

```
event 6020
```

Possessed:

```
event 6030
```

[Here's a list of console commands](http://crusaderkings-two.wikia.com/wiki/Cheats) if you want to add other traits. Or remove them, if you get sick of employing horses as chancellors.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Using console commands feels a bit cheaty to me, but it seems to be the easiest way.

Comment: @Philipp: My take is, cheating is wrong in three cases: when it is used for somehow immoral purposes (like somehow making money using an online game), when it takes away the fun from you, or when it takes fun away from others. Waiting for something unlikely to happen at random does not seem that much more fun than rigging the game to make it happen, unless you let the "cheating" out of hand (making the game too predictable and thus boring). I also can't see how it could be immoral or rob anyone else of his fun (unless they're having fun watching you getting frustrated, in which case, xxx them)

Answer (score 1):

If you own Way of Life DLC, then you can pick learning focus, obtain Necronomicon, and after that there is an option that gives you lunatic trait with 10-15% chance.

Another way is to have a character with a combination of negative traits: paranoid, depressed, zealous, have a fever or being imprisoned - in other words - have conditions that may drive a man to maddness in real life. Than you have to wait.

If you are not afraid to dig into config files of the game, you can search various event files (located in the 'events' folder of the game) for this event:

```
# Become Lunatic
character_event = {
    id = 6020
```

and trace further all the required conditions. You goal is the outcomes with the line

```
add_trait = lunatic
```

and

```
add_trait = possessed
```